# Angular Material - re use the original component css file

Tags: angular-material

I want to extend the Angular material component (mat-table) to override some methods, it works fine for me. and I did all I want, the problem is now I want to use the same table.scss file. I know we can't inherit decorator variables.
is there a way to create my own table.scss and do something like:
@use '@angular/material' as mat;

to use the original table.scss content?

thank you in advance

```
 @Component({
    selector: 'my-mat-table, table[my-mat-table]',
    template: MY_TABLE_TEMPLATE,
    styleUrls: ['table.scss'],
    host: {
        'class': 'mat-mdc-table mdc-data-table__table mat-virtual-table',
        '[class.mdc-table-fixed-layout]': 'fixedLayout',
        'ngSkipHydration': '',
    },
})
export class MyMatTable<T> extends MatTable<T>  {}
```